# How to deploy Rails app + Vue on heroku free plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, heroku

I have made a front-end on vue.js and backend on ruby on rails
I want to deploy it on Heroku Free plan 
Can anyone please guide me with the proper reference documents or Links?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will create a Heroku app for your back-end application, then generate a minified production build of your Vue.js app and then commit and push this file to your app.

This link has more details: https://michaelmeli.com/deployment/2017/09/11/deploying-rails-and-vue-to-heroku.html

Comment: I have front-end and back-end in same directory know as "app"

Comment: The tutorial has all built-in front end in other directories or folder which i dont have !!

Comment: I would highly recommend for you to keep your back and front end separated from each other, they could be inside app folder, but separated. Then you would just build your front-end app from the front-end (client) folder.